InnoSetup how can i know if register key exists
Use the below function in innosetup to locate in register the SketchUp
In my machine i have installed the SketchUp 2024
In registry have default key in
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SketchUp\SketchUp 2024\InstallLocation
but the SketchUpPath returns nothing
what i am doing wrong?
function IsSketchUpInstalled: Boolean;
var
  SketchUpPath: string;
  Year: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for Year := 2010 to 2030 do
  begin
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\SketchUp\SketchUp '+IntToStr(Year)+'\InstallLocation', '', SketchUpPath) then    
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;


Ok i found the solution
I use the HKLM64 instead of HKLM so the function turns into this and works just fine.
function IsSketchUpInstalled: Boolean;
var
  SketchUpPath: string;
  Year: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for Year := 2010 to 2030 do
  begin
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\SketchUp\SketchUp '+IntToStr(Year)+'\InstallLocation', '', SketchUpPath) then    
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

